# Why was this question auto-deleted?

Tags: support, deleted-questions

[This question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/29216/472) sat around at +1 for a while.  It recently picked up a downvote (so score 0) and was auto-deleted by Community.

According to [Turbocharging the Roomba](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173513/turbocharging-the-roomba-solutions-for-premature-deletion/177675#177675), old *closed* questions with no answers and score <= 0 get auto-deleted.  But this question wasn't closed at any point in its history.

Why was it auto-deleted?

Comment: On a phone at the moment, but: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year

Comment: @Shog9 thanks for the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These things often don't see enough velocity for closure, which is why they're culled iteratively. If we restricted the reach to *only* closed questions, a significant amount of stuff that's not likely to help anyone (or worse, blocking someone from asking a better question altogether) wouldn't get deleted.

As Shog notes in comments,  [they get a pretty long life to live](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year) if the community hasn't marked them as potentially harmful with votes, but tend to become things that folks trip over in search engines if they remain in that state for too long.

A *strong* indicator of a good, clear and useful question is it receiving at *least* one answer, ideally one up-voted answer. It could be that some interesting stuff gets caught in that crossfire due to just asking at an unlucky time of day and slipping through the cracks. But, presumably, if it's worth asking - it'll get asked again :)